# Eclipse shows a terribly bad autocompletion when I type "if"

Tags: eclipse

When I type "if" this is what eclipse shows me on auto completion:

[image: autocompletion]

Obviously I want the if statement to be proposed first, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove suggestion using [Type Filters](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fappearance%2Fref-preferences-type-filters.htm):

1. Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters.
2. Click Add to add a package/class.
3. Enter liquibase.pro.packaged
4. Click Apply

> Specify types and packages to hide in the 'Open Type' dialog and content assist or quick fix proposals on this preference page.